# Content of Outdoors is fullscreen in Firefox, instead of a column in the centre

Tags: bug, design

When I look at [The Great Outdoors SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com) using Firefox, my layout changes to fullscreen instead of a central column, which is common on the SE sites.

I'm using Firefox 58.0.2 (32-bits).

When I'm logged in on the same account using Edge, for example, it just looks fine.

[image: Fullscreen layout]

Comment: That is the mobile site.. scroll to bottom and click on full site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've accidentally flipped the 'mobile' switch, so you're seeing the mobile site. Scroll to the footer and click 'full site':

[image]

The switch is set per-site, per-browser, that's why it only affected The Great Outdoors for you, and only on Firefox.